# How to configure a Smart Target facet based on relevance?

Tags: content-delivery, smarttarget

I have a use case where we want to have some facets on our homepage showing content which is related to content we've already shown interest in.  For example:

- Others have also bought...
- You may also be interested in... This facet would show component presentations that are in the same category ordered by popularity

Back in the day with P&P there was (still is in there somewhere) some functionality that tracked clicks and time visited of component presentations.  There was also the ability to write your own custom tracking variables and values into a table in the Broker (via the API of course).

My question is, is there some OOTB tracking with Smart Target/Fred to do this kind of thing, or do we need to develop a custom cartridge tapping into the site's analytics for user tracking stats (e.g. GA, Omniture, Web Trends, etc)?

Comment: Basically the answer is that tracking doesn't exist OOTB, but it is pretty easy to rig it up to put your own custom tracking claims in the Claimstore.

Comment: If you have deeper FH knowledge, you can also hook up your analytics data with ST, by modifying the ETL job and using this data for ranking of promotions...